# Database First not retaining custom schema?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server database that has a rather complex schema that I'm building to interface with my website. There are several custom schemata due to the nature of the data. When I use the built in ADO.NET Entity Model tool in Visual Studio 2013, none of my custom schema is kept, and the name of several of the tables are changed.

How can I retain my database structure while creating the models?

For example, I have 2 tables both called `Employees`. One's schema is `employee`, the other is `companies`, there is already some data in these tables, and it needs to remain there while I'm setting up my models.

Comment: Looks like a feature request already tracked on the EF codeplex site:
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/268
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1363

Comment: @Pawel after some digging around, I've looked into several different solutions, but finally found something that works, it's just time intensive. Several sites said to override the `#OnModelCreating` method, and after attempting this approach, it did not fix the issue. I then tried a different approach. At the head of each class for each table, I placed a `[Table("employees", Schema = "companies")]` And this generates the correct output for migrations.

Comment: because you were using the designer I thought you were doing edmx and not code first. I think you should file this as a bug - the attributes (or corresponding fluent configuration) should be generated for you when you reverse engineer code first.

Comment: I am doing edmx, but having to revise using code so that it creates the database properly

Comment: @Pawel but it does appear to be a bug, if I use two different schemas, but with the same name. It causes an error with the built in migration tool, thinking the tables are the same. After some more searching, this is a common issue, and the only work around seems to be to rename the table.

Comment: @Jsdfighter - if you are doing edmx you should not use attributes or fluent configuration (this is why the template puts `UnintentionalCodeFirstException` to the `OnModelCreating` method) - the model is being read from the edmx and not from the code. Not sure what you refer to as the "built-in migration tool". The edmx itself has information about the schema in the SSDL/StorageModels part so the "built-in migration tool" (whatever it is) should be able to use this information. In CSpace the names are uniquified and there are no duplicates.

Comment: If I go to `Model` and `Add New Item` and select `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`, after selecting my tables, no schema information is retained. It attempts to create all the tables in the database under dbo and uses the class names rather than their original database names.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you create a model from the database or database from model. If you select tables in the wizard how come "it attempts to create all the tables in the database" if you just used them to create a model?

Comment: I apologize if I'm unclear. I've built the database first in SQL Server, but it appears that when it attempts to make the model, it doesn't assign them the proper schema. Now when I run the application, it tells me that `ApplicationDbContext` has been modified and it needs to be updated. So I run `add-migration [Name]` . After viewing the created file, you can see the tables that it want to insert the data into are incorrect. Essentially, it's not retaining table names from my already built database.

Comment: EDMX is not working with Migrations/CodeFirst gracefully. You seem to have created a model from the database but than unintentionally switched to CodeFirst which probably created an entirely new database for you. With EDMX EF does not know if the database changed or not. I think your project is busted now because you think you are using edmx but you are actually using Code First. You can read more about this here: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/

Comment: Thank you for that information! I'm new to Asp.Net and was confused. I took the name `database first` to mean I needed to use that option if I already had an existing database. But it appears I can use code first to integrate with an existing database.

Comment: In fact EF designer 6.1 has this option built in. Install this version and you will have two new options when you start the wizard - one of them will be CodeFirst from existing database. Details are here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/03/17/ef6-1-0-rtm-available.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my error was due to a variety of factors. Apparently there is a bonafide bug in EF6 that causes some errors in retaining schema when using database first. You also run into issues with tables that have the same name. However, a strange fix arose from this method, if you tell the designer to auto pluralize the names, you wouldn't have this strange name collision.

With EF 6.1.0 and the new EF Tools from Microsoft, you can use code-first with an existing database. This method again has a strange bug that if you do not select `pluralize object names` in the designer, you will have naming collisions. But this method does retain the database's schema.